# restart bash script on exit(1) from php script?

Tags: bash, script

I have a php script that works as long as the internet is on. When problems occur, it exits with code 1.

the code in windows looks like this:

```
:start
php myScript.php
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0(
   ECHO "BAD EXECUTION, RESTARTING..."
   GOTO start)
```

I am looking for the equivalent script for linux?

Comment: I hope you put a delay in there someplace because it things error that will do a lot restarting very quickly.

Comment: Possibly relevant:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/negate-while-loop-condition-in-bash   (use `until`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about the same with the addition of sleeps in order not to create a fork bomb:

```
/* edited */
COMMAND="php myScript.php"
SLEEPSEC=10   

$COMMAND 
RC=$?

while [ $RC -eq 1 ] ; do
    echo "BAD EXECUTION, RESTARTING..."
    sleep $SLEEPSEC
    $COMMAND
    RC=$?
done
```

Comment: "-eq: unary operator expected" on line 6

Comment: What does the line: **$COMMAND RC=$?** do?

Comment: COMMAND="php 1.php"  
  
$COMMAND  
exitcode=$?  
  
SLEEPSEC=1  
  
while [ $exitcode -eq 1 ] ; do  
    echo "BAD EXECUTION, RESTARTING..."  
    sleep $SLEEPSEC  
    $COMMAND  
    exitcode=$?  
done

Comment: I used that comment in the end. Thanks for the help!